# Multithreading: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: c#, android, multithreading

I am developing an app in c# where the class is supposed to download and update the userpicture and his landscape picture in an async task:

```
    public PVH_Profile_Header(View itemView, Action<int> listener, Context ctx) : base(itemView)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        LoadContentAsync(ctx);

    }

    private async void LoadContentAsync(Context ctx)
    {
        ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        mDialog.SetMessage(ctx.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Loading));
        mDialog.SetCancelable(false);
        mDialog.Show();

        await InitAvatar(ctx);

        await InitBigPicture(ctx);

        mDialog.Dismiss();
    }
```

but this thows the error from the title.

I tried doing:

```
        Activity.RunOnUiThread(async () =>
        {
            await InitBigPicture(ctx);
        });
```

But this gave me the error (translated:)

```
"For the non-static field, the method needs an reference to an object."
```

If you guys could help me out a little, that be awesome.

Addition info:

This class is a helper class to a recyclerview that is already loading its content async. So I got that to work just fine, but the recyclerview was inside an activity which made the wrapping in "RunOnUiThread" easier.

Thanks!

EDIT:
This is the method "initbigpic:"

```
    private async Task InitBigPicture(Context ctx)
    {
        Bitmap pictures = null;

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {

            if (string.Equals(strUsername, Account.Instance.Username)) // if own profile
            {
                pictures = SaveAccountInfo.LoadLandscapePicFull(0);
            }
            else
            {
                pictures = Intermediate.getLandscapePicture(strUsername, false, 0);
            }


            Drawable intHeitOfDrawable = ctx.Resources.GetDrawableForDensity
                    (Resource.Drawable.thebook_dummyBackgroundBigPicture,
                    (int)ctx.Resources.DisplayMetrics.DensityDpi);

            pictures = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(pictures, ctx.Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels,
                    intHeitOfDrawable.IntrinsicHeight, false);
            btnBigPicture.SetImageBitmap(pictures);

        });

    }
```

Comment: Can you give us the method signature for `InitBigPicture`?

Comment: Also, which line does it throw the exception? Is it when trying to run InitBigPicture?

Comment: hi there! I edited my question! also, it is throwing the line as soon as it is trying to load the recyclerview, it doesnt give me a specific line

Comment: InitBigPicture is not doing anything asynchronous so don't make it async. Rather call the synchronous method with Task.Run (() => {..}) in this case. So RunOnUiThread(async () => { await Task.Run(() => InitBigPicture) }

Comment: can u post this as an answer? i am having trouble reading it the way it is right now! thanks

Comment: I rather not because it's probably not going to solve your problem, just pointing it out from your code. Also try to use async Task instead of async void where ever you can (Like LoadContentAsync should be async Task which would enable you to actually await the call). In UI Code, only place where async void is fine is events.

Comment: okay, I got to work what you said, but this gave me the same error unfortunately :(

Comment: Is something we can't see here in a static class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165431/discussion-between-tjugg-and-innomotion-media).